# Caesar cipher which moves the text about X positions

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a simple code (only c++ strings and loops allowed) which reads a one-line string text as a string and then outputs this string "encrypted by shifting".

It should look like this:

> Please enter the text to be encrypted: **abc def xyz!ABC XYZ?**
>
> Please enter the number of shift positions (as a positive integer):
> **3**
>
> def ghi abc!DEF ABC?

User input is underlined in bold.

And this is how for I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string decrypted_Text, int number_of_movements;

    cout << "Please enter the text to be encrypted: ";
    cin >> decrypted_Text;

    cout << "Please enter the number of shift positions (as a positive integer): ";
    cin >> number_of_movements;

    system("PAUSE");

    return(0);
}
```

I know that text.size() will be used here or rather can imagine that but just don't know how to implement that.

Comment: A for-loop that loops over each character shouldn't be too hard. Start with that. Then figure out how you need to modify each character in the string. In any case StackOverflow is no homework service.

Comment: I did not claim anything like that (regarding the "homework" service).

Comment: Have you even tried compiling (much less tested) what you posted?

Comment: for (unsigned int i = 0, i < decrypted_Text.lenght(); i++) is the way which I did earlier, but for that I would have to sign the value i.

Comment: @ScottHunter Hence why I posted it here because it won't even let me compile.

Comment: Without any mention of it not compiling, or the error message you got?

Comment: @PN911 If you already tried something - great! - it's better to post the failed attempt and any compiler errors you got. It's more useful to ask about and learn from your mistakes then to ask people to write code for you.

Comment: @churill it says "int" type unexpected and undeclared identifier

Comment: You are seeing this error because the character `,` is used to separate the identifiers (ie variable names) of the same type upon declarations. If you want to change the type of the identifier (eg from `string` to `int`) you need to do this in an new command (or that is at least as far as I know). Long story short, try `string decrypted_Text; int number_of_movements;` instead of `string decrypted_Text, int number_of_movements;`. That's because `int` is not a valid identifier, but a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest problems are potential overflows. So, we need to deal with that.

Then we need to understand what Encryption and decryption means. If encryption will shift everthing one to the right, decryption will shift it back to left again.

- So, with "def" and key=1, the encrpyted string will be "efg".
- And decrpytion with key=1, will shift it to left again. Result: "def"

We can observe that we simply need to shift by -1, so the negative of the key.

So, basically encryption and decryption can be done with the same routine. We just need to invert the keys.

Let us look now at the overflow problematic. For the moment we will start with uppercase characters only. Characters have an associated code. For example, in ASCII, the letter 'A' is encoded with 65, 'B' with 66 and so on. Because we do not want to calculate with such number, we normalize them. We simply subtract 'A' from each character. Then

- 'A' - 'A' = 0
- 'B' - 'A' = 1
- 'C' - 'A' = 2
- 'D' - 'A' = 3

You see the pattern. If we want to encrypt now the letter 'C' with key 3, we can do the following.

'C' - 'A' + 3 = 5  Then we add again 'A' to get back the letter and we will get 5 + 'A' = 'F'

That is the whole magic.

But what to do with an overflow, beyond 'Z'. This can be handled by a simple modulo division.

Let us look at 'Z' + 1. We do 'Z' - 'A' = 25, then +1 = 26 and now modulo 26 = 0 then plus 'A' will be 'A'

And so on and so on. The resulting Formula is: (c-'A'+key)%26+'A'

Next, what with negative keys? This is also simple. Assume an 'A' and key=-1

Result will be a 'Z'. But this is the same as shifting 25 to the right. So, we can simply convert a negative key to a positive shift. The simple statement will be:

```
if (key < 0)  key = (26 + (key % 26)) % 26;
```

And then we can call our tranformation function with a simple Lambda. One function for encryption and decrytion. Just with an inverted key.

And with the above formular, there is even no need to check for a negative values. It will work for positive and negative values.

So, `key = (26 + (key % 26)) % 26;` will always work.

---

Some extended information, if you work with ASCII character representation. Please have a look at any ASCII table. You will see that any uppercase and lowercase character differ by 32. Or, if you look in binary:

```
char  dez  bin           char  dez  bin
'A'   65   0100 0001     'a'   97   0110 0001 
'B'   66   0100 0010     'b'   98   0110 0010 
'C'   67   0100 0011     'b'   99   0110 0011 
 . . .
```

So, if you already know that a character is alpha, then teh only difference between upper- and lowercase is bit number 5. If we want to know, if `char`  is lowercase, we can get this by masking this bit. `c & 0b0010 0000` that is equal to `c & 32` or `c & 0x20`.

If we want to operater on either uppercase or lowercase characters, the we can mask the "case" away. With `c & 0b00011111` or `c & 31` or `c & 0x1F` we will get always equivalents for uppercase charcters, already normalized to start with one.

```
char  dez  bin        Masking         char  dez  bin         Masking
'A'   65   0100 0001  & 0x1b = 1      'a'   97   0110 0001   & 0x1b = 1
'B'   66   0100 0010  & 0x1b = 2      'b'   98   0110 0010   & 0x1b = 2
'C'   67   0100 0011  & 0x1b = 3      'b'   99   0110 0011   & 0x1b = 3
 . . .
```

So, if we use an alpha character, mask it, and subtract 1, then we get as a result 0..25 for any upper- or lowercase character.

---

Additionally, I would like tor repeat the key handling. Positive keys will encrypt a string, negative keys will decrypt a string. But, as said above, negative keys can be transormed into positive ones. Example:

```
Shifting by  -1  is same as shifting by  +25
Shifting by  -2  is same as shifting by  +24
Shifting by  -3  is same as shifting by  +23
Shifting by  -4  is same as shifting by  +22
```

So,it is very obvious that we can calculate an always positive key by: `26 + key`. For negative keys, this will give us the above offsets.

And for positve keys, we would have an overflow over 26, which we can elimiate by a modulo 26 division:

```
'A'-->  0 + 26 = 26    26 % 26 = 0 
'B'-->  1 + 26 = 27    27 % 26 = 1 
'C'-->  2 + 26 = 28    28 % 26 = 2 
'D'-->  3 + 26 = 29    29 % 26 = 3
```

--> `(c + key) % 26` will eliminate overflows and result in the correct new en/decryptd character.

And, if we combine this with the bove wisdom for negative keys, we can write: `((26+(key%26))%26)` which will work for all positive and negative keys.

Combining that with that masking, could give us the following program:

```
const char potentialLowerCaseIndicator = c & 0x20;
const char upperOrLower = c & 0x1F;
const char normalized = upperOrLower - 1;
const int withOffset =  normalized + ((26+(key%26))%26);
const int withOverflowCompensation = withOffset % 26;
const char newUpperCaseCharacter = (char)withOverflowCompensation + 'A';
const char result = newUpperCaseCharacter | (potentialLowerCaseIndicator );
```

Of course, all the above many statements can be converted into one Lambda:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

// Simple function for Caesar encyption/decyption
std::string caesar(const std::string& in, int key) {
    std::string res(in.size(), ' ');
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), res.begin(), [&](char c) {return std::isalpha(c) ? (char)((((c & 31) - 1 + ((26 + (key % 26)) % 26)) % 26 + 65) | (c & 32)) : c; });
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::string test{ "aBcDeF xYzZ" };
    std::cout << caesar(test, 5);
}
```

---

The last function can also be made more verbose:

```
std::string caesar1(const std::string& in, int key) {
    std::string res(in.size(), ' ');

    auto convert = [&](const char c) -> char {
        char result = c;
        if (std::isalpha(c)) {

            // Handling of a negative key (Shift to left). Key will be converted to positive value
            if (key < 0) {
                // limit the key to 0,-1,...,-25
                key = key % 26;
                // Key was negative: Now we have someting between 0 and 26
                key = 26 + key;
            };

            // Check and remember if the original character was lower case
            const bool originalIsLower = std::islower(c);

            // We want towork with uppercase only
            const char upperCaseChar = (char)std::toupper(c);

            // But, we want to start with 0 and not with 'A' (65)
            const int normalized = upperCaseChar - 'A';

            // Now add the key
            const int shifted = normalized + key;

            // Addition result maybe bigger then 25, so overflow. Cap it
            const int capped = shifted % 26;

            // Get back a character
            const char convertedUppcase = (char)capped + 'A';

            // And set back the original case
            result = originalIsLower ? (char)std::tolower(convertedUppcase) : convertedUppcase;
        }
        return result;
    };
    std::transform(in.begin(), in.end(), res.begin(), convert);
    return res;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Please see below a solution with only simplest statements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string caesar(string in, int key) {

    // Here we will store the resulting encrypted/decrypted string
    string result{};


    // Handling of a negative key (Shift to left). Key will be converted to positive value
    if (key < 0) {
        // limit the key to 0,-1,...,-25
        key = key % 26;
        // Key was negative: Now we have someting between 0 and 26
        key = 26 + key;
    };
   
    // Read character by character from the string
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < in.length(); ++i) {

        char c = in[i];

        // CHeck for alpha character
        if ((c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z') or (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z')) {

            // Check and remember if the original character was lower case
            bool originalIsLower = (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z');

            // We want to work with uppercase only
            char upperCaseChar = originalIsLower ? c - ('a' - 'A') : c;

            // But, we want to start with 0 and not with 'A' (65)
            int normalized = upperCaseChar - 'A';

            // Now add the key
            int shifted = normalized + key;

            // Addition result maybe bigger then 25, so overflow. Cap it
            int capped = shifted % 26;

            // Get back a character
            char convertedUppcase = (char)capped + 'A';

            // And set back the original case
            result += originalIsLower ? convertedUppcase + ('a' - 'A') : convertedUppcase;

        }
        else
            result += c;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    string test{ "aBcDeF xYzZ" };
    string encrypted = caesar(test, 5);
    string decrypted = caesar(encrypted, -5);

    cout << "Original:  " << test << '\n';
    cout << "Encrpyted: " << encrypted << '\n';
    cout << "Decrpyted: " << decrypted << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Code is careful about `key < 0`, but not `c < 0`.  That is an issue with `is...(c)`.  Consider `unsigned char c;`

Comment: You're unfortunately covering topics we haven't had yet.

Comment: @PN911: I am sorry for that. I tried to give a detailed expalanation. What is too much and shall be deleted and what shall I explain better? Then I will edit my answer.

Comment: #include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
const,
auto are the things that we haven't had yet.

Comment: I edited the answer and added a simple version at the bottom. Is this now acceptable for you or do you need more explanations/modifications?

Comment: chux - Reinstate Monica: I guess there will be now problem, because I restricted it to alpha characters. The whole program can easily be adapted to a wider rang of printable characters, by using a different modulo divisor (e.g. 94) and subtracting for example a 'space' (32)